# Write shell script by taking table name as parameter and executing hive query

Tags: bash, shell, hive

I'm trying to build a shell script that takes table_name as parameter and run the below hive query.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/data/table_name' 
row format delimited
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz No it doesn't. The OP didn't mention what they have already tried or what doesn't work specifically.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need it:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]; then exit 1; fi    
printf -v TAB "%q" "$1"
/usr/bin/mysql -NBe "INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/data/table_$TAB' row format delimited FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' SELECT * FROM $TAB"
```